# Could not find or load main java class jar on AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: java, linux, gradle, amazon-ec2, jar

I need to run on `Linux` on `AWS EC2` me `jar` file.
I have a `multi-project` on `Gradle`.
I know that there are many analogs of my problem, but I did not find anything with the `multi-project`.

The structure of my project is as follows

```
demo
   -core
       com.example
       build.gradle
   -web
       build.gradle
       com.example
          DemoApplication.java(main)
   build.gradle
```

My `build.gradle` in demo.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-class' : 'com.example.DemoApplication'
    }
}


configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I execute the command `jar`, I get `jar` file that I run on `Linux` `java -jar '/home/ec2-user/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar'` and it gives me an error.

> Could not find or load main class com.example.DemoApplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, I tricky with the `Gradle` and `Spring-boot` versions.
What did I do to make it work:

1. Created a new project in [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) with `Java 11` and `Spring Boot 2.5.8(SNAPSHOT)`.
2. Moved the whole project to a new one.
3. I also used 2 commands before `gradle clean` and `gradle build`. And in the working version I used `gradlew clean build`.
4. And launched the `jar` file in `Linux` as usual.

Hope it helps someone someday :)